# Take iPhone App Screenshot from Organizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How do I take iPhone App Screenshot from Organizer? I mean in XCode, what profile should I select and what settings/values?

Comment: There aren't any "settings/values" to select... you just plug in your device, choose the Screenshots tab and click Capture.

Comment: I am aware of that...But if u read my question correctly, my question is ; what profile do I select in XCode

Comment: None. Any. Whatever you like. It doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Like I said, just plug in your device and take a screenshot.

Comment: It's simply adorable how anyone can consider my first comment noise, offensive or spam.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're over thinking this. Just open the organizer, select the attached device, click on the "Screenshots" tab, and click "Take Screenshot".

To find the files later, by default they are saved in

```
Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Screenshots/
```

Comment: Or you can just drag them from the Organizer to the desktop.

Comment: I do not see "Take Screenshot"...In fact the "Build & Run" option is disabled in the Organizer...even though I can do the same from within XCode..

Comment: You are not looking in the Organizer. This has nothing whatsoever to do with any particular project. This is about a device that is plugged in to the computer. If it's not plugged in, you obviously cannot take the screenshot. Close all projects, open the Organizer, plug a device into the port, select the plugged in device, and it will all work beautifully.